# Visual C# completely ignoring FormClosing event

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My application appears to be skipping the Form_Closing event entirely, and I am not sure why. I have tried to debug it by using e.cancel and showing a messagebox when it closes, but the messagebox never shows, and the e.cancel doesnt cancel it. My code is

```
    public void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isClosed == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
            this.Hide();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: check your boolean isClosed value? kindly put the code inside base.OnFormClosing(e); as well.

Comment: Are you using application. Exit or just abruptly closing the application.  Also,  check the value of isclosed is not true

Comment: I have attempted to put the messagebox in the else statement and it didn't show so it isn't the boolean. @Shon

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I'm not sure what the base.OnFormClosing(e) is?

Comment: then remove it, make sure Form1_FormClosing is mapped with your form and not just a declaration.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I will link a pastebin to the full code, it is in the form area.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch http://pastebin.com/feh17LkR

Comment: paste your Form1.designer.cs as well. you should found Form1_FormClosing event there if not then the event is not mapped.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch http://pastebin.com/RDe2X3uM

Comment: @Tyler, my assumption is correct the Form1_FormClosing is not mapped. in your form design time go to the events properties of the form and mapped the event.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Hi, how might I do this? Sorry, I'm new to C#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112012/discussion-between-tyler-and-dr-stitch).

Comment: Sorry no access to chat.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has the signature appropriate for a FormClosing event handler, but you are calling `base.OnFormClosing` which is only appropriate for an `OnFormClosing` override.

Pick one.  For example, the override would look like

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isClosed == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
            Hide();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Tyler: Great, the error message told you exactly how to fix it.  Learn to read error messages and help yourself.

Comment: um... ok. Not getting much luck from Google.

Comment: @Tyler: The error message says "Cannot change access modifiers when overriding", and also helpfully tells you that the existing access modifier is `protected`.

Answer (score -1):

Start by only using a message box to determine that you hace the right event
Then check the value of isclosed since I suspect it is true.

Comment: I also tested putting the messagebox in the else{} as well, and it did not work. Using just a messagebox also did not work

Comment: I suspect that the code is in the wrong area. Use the event list of the forn and use form closing from there